# Failed to complete Gradle execution cause: org/gradle/Internal/TrueTimeProvider

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, runtime, build.gradle

I am new to Android and while I am building project I am getting this type of error:

> Failed to complete Gradle execution cause: org/gradle/Internal/TrueTimeProvider

I searched a lot through Google and Stack Overflow but no help.

Comment: What is your current grade version ?

Comment: please provide your gradle info at both lavel project and app

Comment: Project level gradle version is :  **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'**


App level :
**build tool version 25.0.0
target sdk version 25
Android repository version 25.2.0
play service version 10.2.1**

Comment: Without an [mcve], people probably cannot help you, and the question will need to be put on hold.

Answer (score 1):

For me was fixed removing this from my app `build.gradle`:

```
buildtimetracker {
    reporters {
        csv {
            output "build/times.csv"
            append true
            header false
        }

        summary {
            ordered false
            threshold 50
            barstyle "unicode"
        }

        csvSummary {
            csv "build/times.csv"
        }
    }
}
```

and this

```
classpath "net.rdrei.android.buildtimetracker:gradle-plugin:0.8.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try performing a clean build from build->clean project

Answer (score 0):

Download any gradle of version greater than 3.2 
link : https://services.gradle.org/distributions/

Extract it and save it in a suitable place in your computer.
Open android studio and open settings.

**File->Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Gradle**

[image]

on the right side choose or select Use local gradle distribution
and then browse to where you had saved your downloaded extracted gradle
click apply, then ok.

**Don't forget to invalidate cache if you have some trouble using File -> Invalidate Cache / Restart**

Comment: Can you provide your app gradle and project gradle info ? just post the snap of it