# Project refresh failed - Error:Cause: org/gradle/internal/TrueTimeProvider

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Importing this project from github, I've run into this message:

```
Gradle 'GameOfLife-master' project refresh failed
Error:Cause: org/gradle/internal/TrueTimeProvider
```

I've tried solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42968399/failed-to-complete-gradle-execution-cause-org-gradle-internal-truetimeprovider), cleaned/rebuilt (at least attempted to) the project, invalidated caches and tried a different version of Gradle. None of that worked. Anyone else got any ideas?

Module: app - build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        classpath "com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8"
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.1.0'
        classpath "net.rdrei.android.buildtimetracker:gradle-plugin:0.5.+"
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'hu.supercluster:paperwork-plugin:1.2.7'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'hugo'
apply plugin: "build-time-tracker"
apply plugin: 'hu.supercluster.paperwork'

paperwork {
    set = [
            gitInfo:   gitInfo(),
            gitSha:    gitSha(),
            buildTime: buildTime("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "GMT+01:00")
    ]
}

def versionMajor = 1
def versionMinor = 2
def versionPatch = 0

android {
    compileSdkVersion androidCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion androidBuildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'hu.supercluster.gameoflife'
        minSdkVersion androidMinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion androidTargetSdkVersion

        versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 100 + versionPatch
        versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"

        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        alpha {}
        beta {}
        release {}
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix "-debug"
            resValue "string", "app_name_for_buildtype", "Game of Life (debug)"
            minifyEnabled false
            testCoverageEnabled = false
        }

        alpha {
            applicationIdSuffix ".alpha"
            versionNameSuffix "-alpha"
            resValue "string", "app_name_for_buildtype", "Game of Life (alpha)"
            minifyEnabled false
            testCoverageEnabled = false
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
            }
        }

        beta {
            applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
            versionNameSuffix "-beta"
            resValue "string", "app_name_for_buildtype", "Game of Life (beta)"
            minifyEnabled false
            testCoverageEnabled = false
        }

        release {
            resValue "string", "app_name_for_buildtype", "Game of Life"
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        // src/gen is the target for generated content like json model
        java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/db'
    }

    // avoid errors with message 'Duplicate files copied in APK ...'
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}

afterEvaluate {
    def propsFile = rootProject.file('keystore.properties')
    def configName = 'release'

    if (propsFile.exists() && android.signingConfigs.hasProperty(configName)) {
        def props = new Properties()
        props.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile))
        android.signingConfigs[configName].storeFile = rootProject.file(props['storeFile'])
        android.signingConfigs[configName].storePassword = props['storePassword']
        android.signingConfigs[configName].keyAlias = props['keyAlias']
        android.signingConfigs[configName].keyPassword = props['keyPassword']
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'

    // ---------

    compile 'com.github.tslamic.adn:library:1.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') { transitive = true }
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:2.5.1'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.6'
    compile 'hu.supercluster:paperwork:1.2.7'

    // ---------

    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:" + androidAnnotationsVersion
    compile("org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:" + androidAnnotationsAPIVersion )

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    testCompile('com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+') { exclude module: 'support-v4' }
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"

    androidTestCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1',
            'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.1.0',
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1',
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1',
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1',
            'com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r3'
}

apt {
    arguments {
        resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.applicationId
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0]?.processResources?.manifestFile
    }
}

apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        //and some extra test source dirs
        testSourceDirs += file('src/test')
    }
}

apply from: 'build-time-tracker.gradle'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run with `--stacktrace` to get a full exception stack trace

Gradle has the concept of `public` API and `private` API. Basically anything in `org.gradle.internal` is a part of the private API and the gradle team can change / remove these classes between gradle versions. Ideally plugins should never reference `internal` classes. Any plugin author referencing `internal` API's must understand that this code may break with a new release of Gradle.

It looks like one of your plugins is referencing the `internal` API (`org.gradle.internal.TrueTimeProvider`) and the plugin was built against one version of Gradle and you are running with a different version of gradle.

To fix, you'll need to determine which plugin is throwing the exception (`--stacktrace` will help here). Then you'll either need to change the plugin version to one compatible with your version of gradle, or change the gradle version you are running with.

Comment: My goal is to just the get the App running, so I tried setting the custom location to a newer version of gradle (3.5 and 4.0rc), but it gave the same result in the end.

Changing the build.gradle classpath for gradle to 3.5.0 instead of 2.3.2 makes it unable to find the library, even though I've set it up. It's searching for gradle-3.5.0.jar and that file can't be found inside the gradle folder.

Android Monitor is empty and shows no messages.

Thanks for the thorough answer.

Comment: Just a guess... but I'd try commenting out `apply plugin: "build-time-tracker"`. Also dynamic build numbers are problematic (eg `0.5.+` and `1.+`). Much better to use specific versions

Comment: I try to use specific versions, but this isn't my project.

Commenting out "build-time-tracker" solved the original problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're just lucky I could take an educated guess from the class name and plugin name. A stacktrace would've helped here